# .NET MVC add custom headers to all 302 responses

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, sitefinity

I currently have an mvc app which sits behind a secure, third-party gateway. This gateway is cacheing 302 responses which in some scenarios is resulting in an endless loop of loading screens in my application. Im trying to find a way to add custom headers to the response but only for 302s as I never want them cached however my application does need to cache resources of other status codes. I know I can use:

```
<httpProtocol> 
  <customHeaders> 
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" /> 
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" /> 
  </customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
```

however this will set the cache headers for all responses and not only 302s. How can I achieve the same behavior but only for 302 redirects?

I've also tried creating a custom filter for it as follows:

```
public class CustomCacheHeaderFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if(actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
        {
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        }
    }
}
```

and registering in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new CustomCacheHeaderFilter());
}
```

however this doesn't seem to have any effect. Note this is a Sitefinity MVC application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `<httpProtocol>` section of the web.config supports a section which only affects redirects named `<redirectHeaders>`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/redirectheaders/index) for the docs. Example usage that solved my issue is as follows:

```
<httpProtocol> 
  <redirectHeaders> 
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" /> 
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" /> 
  </redirectHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
```